# CCLocation (iPhone SDK) accuracy

Tags: iphone, geolocation, cllocation

How accurate is the CCLocation class? 20 meters? more or less? Because I'd like to get the most accurate values from the user's location.

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request the accuracy desired using the [desiredAccuracy property of CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).  But the actual accuracy delivered depends on other factors generally outside your control including whether the device is using GPS, cell tower, or wifi.